# Does Ajax - cross domain request return the request header?

Tags: javascript, ajax, http-headers, cross-domain, same-origin-policy

I know that the ajax-cross domain call will not return the data from server.

however, does it return a http header, like 200, 404..etc?

Comment: If an HTTP request is sent, then a HTTP response (with header) is sure to follow... (except the server is down, of course)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't actually fire the request.  If it did, CSRF would be almost impossible to stop...

You can read more about it [here](http://www.w3.org/Security/wiki/Same_Origin_Policy) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript)

But, if you want to fetch content from a different source, check out [JSONP](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-aj-jsonp1/)

Comment: the weird thing is. i do a test (on FX), the server actually gets the request, but not firing response.  that's strange.  that's why i ask this question.

Comment: @mur: FX?  Are you talking about FireFox?  What version?

Comment: @ircmaxwell: He's right. Some browsers will send an OPTIONS request instead of a GET request, so the server actually will receive the request, but it won't handle it.

Comment: but in any case, it will not send back a http response, right?